# How to do async / await video streaming with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, video-streaming

Recently I read this article (https://blogs.ibs.com/2017/01/24/streaming-video-content-to-a-browser-using-web-api) about video streaming.

The solution provided in the article works pretty but I was wondering if there was any async / await alternatives since the article only show a solution built around `HttpResponseMessage` and I am worried about performance issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance wise there should be no problem.

Using async await is not going to provide much of an improvement. The `FileStreamer` is already taking advantage of async operations in accessing the file stream.

If you insist on using async await, you can consider wrapping the body of the action in a `Task.Run` and having the action return a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`.

There really is no need for premature optimization here.

Review any potential blocking calls and refactor accordingly

For example

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string filename) {

    var filePath = await GetFilePathAsync(filename);
    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        return NotFound();

    var response = getResponse(filePath);

    return ResponseMessage(response);
}

private HttpResponseMessage getResponse(string filePath) {
    var response = Request.CreateResponse();
    response.Headers.AcceptRanges.Add("bytes");

    var streamer = new FileStreamer();
    streamer.FileInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
    response.Content = new PushStreamContent(streamer.WriteToStream, GetMimeType(filePath));

    RangeHeaderValue rangeHeader = Request.Headers.Range;
    if (rangeHeader != null) {
        long totalLength = streamer.FileInfo.Length;
        var range = rangeHeader.Ranges.First();
        streamer.Start = range.From ?? 0;
        streamer.End = range.To ?? totalLength - 1;

        response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = streamer.End - streamer.Start + 1;
        response.Content.Headers.ContentRange = new ContentRangeHeaderValue(streamer.Start, streamer.End,
            totalLength);
        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.PartialContent;
    } else {
        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }
    return response;
}
```